# SQL Server shift based weekday, weekend, public holiday and time of the day

Tags: sql-server, view

Need help with creating a view for an existing table where there is a datetime column and it has to be divided into shifts based on the day of the week, hour of the day. For example during the weekdays the shifts should be between 6, 15 and 24, I mean 0 to 6 night shift, 6 to 15 morning etc.

In Excel I've done with nested ifs and I don't know how to do it with multiple case when statements.

```
IF([Day]="Monday";IF(AND([Hour]>=6;[Hour]<14);"Morning";IF(AND([Hour]>=14;[Hour]<22);"Afternoon";"N"));
IF([Day]="Wednesday";IF(AND([Hour]>=6;[Hour]<14);"Morning";IF(AND([Hour]>=14;[Hour]<22);"Afternoon";"N"));
IF([Day]="Friday";IF(AND([Hour]>=6;[Hour]<14);"Morning";IF(AND([Hour]>=14;[Hour]<22);"Afternoon";"N")); 

ID Logtime             Shift
-------------------------------
1  2019-10-17 00:05:00 Night
2  2019-10-17 05:55:00 Night
3  2019-10-17 06:05:00 Morning
4  2019-10-17 14:55:00 Morning
5  2019-10-17 15:05:00 Evening
6  2019-10-17 23:55:00 Evening
```

I was able to do it for one day with the following code but not for several days.

```
case    
   when DATENAME(WEEKDAY, LogTime) = 'Thursday' and DATEPART(hour, LogTime) < 6  
      then 'Night'
   when DATENAME(WEEKDAY, LogTime) = 'Thursday' and DATEPART(hour, LogTime) >= 6 and DATEPART(hour, logtime) < 15 
      then 'Morning' 
   else 'Evening'
end as Shift
```

I hope someone can help and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thank you Larnu for editing

Comment: If you've achieved this in Excel, posting that code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of complex case statements, I recommend using a table for days and shifts.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE (ID INT, Logtime  DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
(1, '2019-10-17 00:05:00'),
(2, '2019-10-17 05:55:00'),
(3, '2019-10-17 06:05:00'),
(4, '2019-10-17 14:55:00'),
(5, '2019-10-17 15:05:00'),
(6, '2019-10-17 23:55:00')


SET DATEFIRST  1

SELECT T.*, Shifts.Shift FROM 
    @SampleData T
    INNER JOIN (VALUES ( 1, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 1, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 1, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 2, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 2, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 2, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 3, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 3, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 3, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 4, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 4, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 4, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 5, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 5, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 5, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 6, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 6, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 6, 15, 24,'Evening'),
                       ( 7, 0,  6,'Night'), ( 7, 6,  15,'Morning'), ( 7, 15, 24,'Evening') ) Shifts(DayOfW, SDate, EDate, Shift) ON 
                                                                DATEPART(WEEKDAY,T.Logtime) = Shifts.DayOfW
                                                            AND DATEPART(HOUR,T.Logtime) >= Shifts.SDate 
                                                            AND DATEPART(HOUR,T.Logtime) < Shifts.EDate
```

Result:

```
ID          Logtime                 Shift
----------- ----------------------- -------
1           2019-10-17 00:05:00.000 Night
2           2019-10-17 05:55:00.000 Night
3           2019-10-17 06:05:00.000 Morning
4           2019-10-17 14:55:00.000 Morning
5           2019-10-17 15:05:00.000 Evening
6           2019-10-17 23:55:00.000 Evening
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just nesting case .... when .... then ... end as follow:

```
case DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @LogTime)
when 'Monday'  then case when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < 6 then 'Night'
                          when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= 6 and 
                               DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) < 15 then 'Morning' 
                                                             else 'Evening'
                     end
when 'Tuesday' then case when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < 6 then 'Night'
                          when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= 6 and 
                               DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) < 15 then 'Morning' 
                                                             else 'Evening'
                     end
when 'Wednesday' then case when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < 6 then 'Night'
                          when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= 6 and 
                               DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) < 15 then 'Morning' 
                                                             else 'Evening'
                     end
when 'Thursday' then case when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < 6 then 'Night'
                          when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= 6 and 
                               DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) < 15 then 'Morning' 
                                                             else 'Evening'
                     end
when 'Friday' then case when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < 6 then 'Night'
                          when DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= 6 and 
                               DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) < 15 then 'Morning' 
                                                             else 'Evening'
                     end
             else 'weekend'
end
```

But it would be more elegant to use instead scalar functions, in ordervto avoid repetitive patterns.

Comment: I see, could you please reply me as function instead? Thanks.

Comment: I can, but replies in stackoverflow allow only for 600 characters with mini-Markdown formatting which prevents to copy paste the whole thing. I will instead post it as another answer. And you will see from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing it would be to use scalar function instead as below

First let's create a function that return the shift name
according the time morning shift starts and when it ends

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('ufn_DayPart', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION ufn_DayPart;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_DayPart(
    @LogTime datetime, 
    @MorningShiftStart int, 
    @MorningShiftEnd int)
RETURNS 
    VARCHAR(10)AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, @LogTime)  < @MorningShiftStart then 'Night'
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) >= @MorningShiftStart and 
                     DATEPART(hour, @LogTime) <  @MorningShiftEnd   then 'Morning' 
                                                                    else 'Evening'
           END
END
GO
```

Now putting it in the perspective of a week
let's create a function in which shift might start or end
at different time depending of the day of the week

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('ufn_GetShift', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION ufn_GetShift;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_GetShift(
    @LogTime datetime)
RETURNS 
    VARCHAR(10)AS
BEGIN
    RETURN case DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @LogTime)
                when 'Monday'    then dbo.ufn_DayPart(@LogTime, 6, 15 )
                when 'Tuesday'   then dbo.ufn_DayPart(@LogTime, 6, 15 )
                when 'Wednesday' then dbo.ufn_DayPart(@LogTime, 6, 15 )
                when 'Thursday'  then dbo.ufn_DayPart(@LogTime, 6, 15 )
                when 'Friday'    then dbo.ufn_DayPart(@LogTime, 6, 15 )
                                 else 'weekend'
                END
END
GO
```

Now, let's try it in very simple queries:

```
begin
declare @LogTime as datetime
set @LogTime = '2019-09-29 01:10'    SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
set @LogTime = '2019-09-30 20:10'    SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
set @LogTime = '2019-10-01 12:10'    SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
set @LogTime = '2019-10-02 06:00'    SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
set @LogTime = '2019-10-02 05:59:59' SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
set @LogTime = '2019-10-03 19:10'    SELECT @LogTime, dbo.ufn_GetShift(@LogTime) as shift
end
```

In your queries it would look like:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, dbo.ufn_GetShift(col_timeLog) as shift
FROM YourTable
```

I hope I made it more clear this way